# How to loop back to beginning of the String? Hyperskill, encryption - decryption

Tags: java, string, loops, encryption

im doing the Hyperskill Encryption - Decryption project, **description below** and i ran into a problem.
for example, It works fine if i try to encrypt the letter = a key = 1, the output will be: b.
but it will not work if the letter = z, key = 1, the method should loop back to the beginning of alphabet and the output should be a.
The question is - how can i make my method loop back to the beginning if it has to do it?

**The description of the project:**

> Write a program that reads an English message and an integer number
>   (key)  from the standard input and shifts each letter by the specified
>   number according to its order in the alphabet.  If you reach the end
>   of the alphabet, start back at the beginning (a follows z).
>
> The English alphabet is below: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
>
> The program should not modify non-letter characters. The key is
>   assumed to mean that if a person knows the value of the key,  he or
>   she will be able to decrypt the text,  and if he or she does not know,
>   he or she will not be able to decrypt the text.  It's like a real key
>   that can open up access to the message text.

```
public static void encrypt(String input, int key) {
        String output = "";
        String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            String inputCharacter = Character.toString(input.charAt(i));
            if (inputCharacter.equals(" ")) {
                output += " ";
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < alphabet.length(); j++) {
                String alphabetCharacter = Character.toString(alphabet.charAt(j));
                String decryptedCharacter = Character.toString(alphabet.charAt(j) + key);

                if (inputCharacter.equals(alphabetCharacter)) {
                    output += decryptedCharacter;
                }

            }
        }
        System.out.println(output);


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the modulo operator `%` to "wrap around" large indices to the length of the string:

```
String decryptedCharacter = Character.toString(alphabet.charAt((j + key) % alphabet.length()));
```

(Note the parens: In your original code, you were adding `key` to the `char`, not to the index.)

Also, you can use `contains` to check if a character is in the alphabet to handle e.g. punctuation:

```
if (! alphabet.contains(inputCharacter)) {
     output += inputCharacter;
}
```